# AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'manager1'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am getting an error :

> Attribute error: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'manager1' when I am trying to switch to another screen using their respective id's.

This is my code:

Python file:

- Inside the `First_Screen()` class

```py
My2App.first.manager1.current = "start"   #"start" is the name of First_Screen()
```

- This is my `My2App` class

```py
class My2App(MDApp):
    manager1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    first = ObjectProperty(None)
    second = ObjectProperty(None)
        
    def build(self):
        self.bd = Builder.load_file("My.kv")
        return self.bd
```

kv file:

```
ScreenManager:
    manager1:manager1
    id:manager1

    First_Screen:
        first:first
        id:first
    Show_Title:
        second:second
        id:second

<First_Screen>:
    name:'start'

    # rest of the content.....
```

I don't understand what is missing.
Thanks for helping me in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy/paste your code, it doesn't work. I had to changes multiples before even having a working code or having the error that you are talking about.
So here is a working code.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class My2App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.bd = Builder.load_file("My.kv")
        return self.bd

My2App().run()
```

```
<First_Screen>:


ScreenManager:
    id:manager1

    Screen:
        id:first
        name:'start'

    Screen:
        id:second
        second:second



    # rest of the content.....
```

Comment: My code has thousands of code and I shared with you a part of my code so that you wont get confused try again without copy pasting

Comment: my app have ten of thousands of lines of code but I still post working example. If you can't create a working mvp and isolate the problem,  you must work on yourself first then ask in SO. I have been banned in the past for more explicit post than this one. I'm maybe brutal but that's how it works, you gonna improve and understand what I mean but for the moment, this post is not good enough because I had to pass time just to get a working example or make the error that you mentionned appear.